# Triangle in layout - Android UI

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I need to add/design the next triangle in an Android layout.
Above the triangle the layout background is gray, and below is white.

[image]

Basically is a gray triangle with a dark border and a red border, but i dont know which is the best way to archieve this.
I dont want to add static images to the layout, and i dont know how to do this with shapes,xml,drawables.

Comment: You can't with xml drawables.  They're very limited.  You need an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do some tweaking for your particular layout but here's an example.  (The heights & widths come from something else I was working on.  That's one of the things you'll have determine for your layout).

triangle_background.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="96dp"
    android:width="64dp"

    android:viewportWidth="400"
    android:viewportHeight="600">

    <!-- upper white area -->
    <path android:pathData="M 0 112 l 200,50 200,-50 V 0 H 0 z"
        android:fillColor="#ffffff" android:strokeColor="#ffffff" android:strokeWidth="2" />

    <!-- black line -->
    <path android:pathData="M 0 117 l 200,50 200,-50"
        android:strokeColor="#000000" android:strokeWidth="5" />

    <!-- red line -->
    <path android:pathData="M 0 130 l 200,50 200,-50"
        android:strokeColor="#ff0000" android:strokeWidth="20" />

    <!-- lower grey area -->
    <path android:pathData="M 0 135 l 200,50 200,-50 V 600 H 0 z"
        android:fillColor="#aaaaaa" android:strokeColor="#aaaaaa" android:strokeWidth="2" />
</vector>
```

And here is the layout file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/triangle_background"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:text="button"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

indeed you can, you can design in any vector design program like adobe illustrator and import it as SVG and later import it to the android studio as SVG android studio will automatically convert it to XML
right click on drawable folder >> Vector asset

[image]

if you want to know how to design it you can ask here https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/